# How to get cart item id using product id in magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I want to get cart item id using product id. For example, my product id is 600 and item id is 250.

using product id , want to get cart item id.

How to get it ?

please help me..

Answer (score 2):

```
$productid = 600;
$quote = $this->checkoutHelper->getQuote();

foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
  $cartproductid = $_item->getProductId();
  if($productid==$cartproductid)
  {
    your_item_id = $_item->getId();
 }
}
```

Comment: One thing also... can you tell me about how to mini cart reload/refresh..